# How we can skip a SCM project in Jenkins in case of multiple SCM projects?

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control

I have multiple `SCM` set in your Jenkins `SCM` projects and running Poll `SCM` for triggering a build but the issue is some time if anyone of the git servers is down for maintenance the whole build gets to failure which is impacting other `SCM` projects. Jenkins has a procedure of checking and executing `git fetch` for every `SCM` projects which is set in the `SCM` section and when it encounters a git server which is down it abort as a failure, I'm looking for a solution where I can set some setting which results in Jenkins skip specific git `SCM` projects while checking for commits and move to another one. Is any feature available for this?